# How to setup Spark Executor log rolling

Tags: scala, apache-spark, configuration

Within our project, we have multiple streaming applications, and I'm looking to implement log rolling specifically for the Spark Executors without causing disruptions to other spark application. I'm currently facing challenges in figuring out the correct approach. Although I've configured spark-submit with the settings below, the log rolling doesn't seem to be functioning as expected. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
  $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --name iot_engine \
  --master yarn \
  --class $CLASSNAME \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=conf/*" \
  --conf spark.yarn.tags=$APPTAG \
  --files $CONF_FILES \
  --executor-cores $EXECUTORCORES \
  --num-executors $NUMEXECUTORS \
  --conf spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=24 \
  --conf spark.yarn.executor.failuresValidityInterval=2m \
  --conf spark.task.maxFailures=10 \
  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=10 \
  --conf spark.yarn.am.attemptFailuresValidityInterval=2m \
  --conf spark.scheduler.allocation.file=fairscheduler.xml \
  --conf spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR \
  --conf spark.scheduler.pool=primary \
  --conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false \
  --conf spark.yarn.jars=hdfs://$HDFS_CLUSTER/spark/jars/*.jar \
  --conf "spark.executor.logs.rolling.time.interval=hourly" \
  --conf "spark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy=time" \
  --conf "spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles=7" \
  $IOTENGINE_JARPATH
```

My log4j.properties

```
    # Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, SysErr
    log4j.logger.dt.cerebrum.iotengine=INFO, SysOut, SysErr
    log4j.logger.com.sksamuel=DEBUG
    log4j.additivity.dt.cerebrum.iotengine=false
    # Direct info log messages to SysOut
    log4j.appender.SysOut=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.SysOut.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.SysOut.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.SysOut.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
    log4j.appender.SysOut.filter.y=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
    log4j.appender.SysOut.filter.y.LevelMin=INFO
    log4j.appender.SysOut.filter.y.LevelMax=INFO
    # Direct error log messages to SysErr
    log4j.appender.SysErr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.SysErr.Target=System.err
    log4j.appender.SysErr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.SysErr.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
    log4j.appender.SysErr.filter.y=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
    log4j.appender.SysErr.filter.y.LevelMin=ERROR
    log4j.appender.SysErr.filter.y.LevelMax=ERROR
```

I want rolling for sysout and syserr logs, Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly helpful. Thanks.